# Cloud foundry SSH not working

Tags: node.js, ssh, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I am not able to make SSH working.
I checked that SSH is enable on the Application and Space level. 
But when i ran

`cf ssh "MY-APP-NAME"` i get the following error:

```
FAILED
Error: SSH session allocation failed: ssh: unexpected packet in response to 
channel open: <nil>
```

I also tried to connect without CLi and using the command

`ssh -p 2222 cf:abcdefab-1234-5678-abcd-1234abcd1234/0@ssh.MY-DOMAIN.com`
But when i entered the password the server stopped the connection (i used Putty).

I am trying to access with SSH because i need to launch `npm install` to install the dependencies of my application.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please check that:
1. your space developer in the space the app is running
2. ssh is anabled on space level
3. ssh in enabled on app level
then try again using cf ssh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to ssh into an app to install dependencies.
Please have a look at Swisscoms Getting Started Guide for Node.js:
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/tutorial-nodejs/index.html
The section 'Declare App Dependencies' (https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/tutorial-nodejs/dependencies.html) shows you how you specify the dependencies in a file called 'package.json'. This will then be automatically installed by the nodejs buildpack (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nodejs-buildpack).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I then have another issue.